# How to tell RandomizedSearchCV to choose from distribution or None value?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, random-forest, hyperparameters

Let's say we are trying to find best `max_depth` parameter of [`RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier). We are using [`RandomizedSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html):

```
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

rf_params = {              # Is this somehow possible?
              'max_depth': [sp_randint(1, 100), None],
            }

n_iter = 10

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), 
                                   verbose=50, 
                                   param_distributions=rf_params,
                                   n_iter=n_iter, 
                                   n_jobs=-1, 
                                   scoring='f1_micro')

random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Is it possible to tell `RandomizedSearchCV` to either choose from specified distribution `sp_randint(1, 100)` OR set parameter to `None` which will (as in docs): *"...expand are nodes until all leaves are pure or until all leaves contain less than min_samples_split samples..."*?

When I run this code right now I will get this error:

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV): "If a list is given, it is sampled uniformly." Use this:

```
'max_depth': list(range(1, 100)) + [None]
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but there is now really small chance to randomly choose `None` from such list, can this somehow be improved?

Comment: What is "improved" to you? I ask because if you want the guarantee that it's chosen, you're better off with GridSearchCV.

Comment: Well maybe some different distribution than uniform, let's say geometric (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.geom.html#scipy.stats.geom) where None would have high probability P(x=None).

Comment: Such distributions make sense if you let `None` be a stand-in for some other value that belongs in the distribution. Thinking about the problem domain you have in mind, what should be replaced?

Comment: Well if we have `geom(p=0.5, loc=0)` then `None` could be stand-in for value `0`. But would my `RandomForestClassifier` figure out that `max_depth=0` stands for `max_depth=None` ?

Comment: For @PeterB's first comment-question here, there's a simple hack: just repeat the `None` option many times: `list(range(1, 100)) + [None]*50`.